zombie process problems
When I run a Winforms application on a particular PC, if an exception is thrown before the UI Thread is created, a zombie process is created.
// .NET Framework 4.8

using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestApp
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            // test code
            //AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

            throw new NotImplementedException();

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }

    private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // do somethings..
        }
        finally
        {
            // Environment.Exit(0); // It works well.
            Application.Exit(); // Zombie!!
        }
    }
}


C:\Users\foo>tasklist | findstr Test // running
TestApp.exe                   4836 Console                    1     32,256 K

C:\Users\foo>tasklist | findstr Test // exception
TestApp.exe                   4836 Console                    1     41,532 K
TestApp.exe                  15132 Console                    1         36 K

C:\Users\foo>tasklist | findstr Test
TestApp.exe                  15132 Console                    1         20 K

C:\Users\foo>taskkill /F /PID 15132
Error: Unable to terminate process (PID 15132) 
Reason: Access denied:  

On my PC or my coworker's PC, the process is killed normally, so what is causing the process to live instead of being killed?
The same thing happens if you handle it with the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event.
Here are the specifications of the PC on which the zombie process occurs:
Processor AMD Ryzen 7 5800U with Radeon Graphics            1.90 GHz
Installed RAM 16.0 GB (13.8GB available)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64 based processor

Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 23H2
Installation Date Tuesday 22-09-27
OS Build 22631.3374
Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22688.1000.0

.NET Version : 4.8.1


Additionally, calling Environment.Exit(0) rather than Application.Exit() when the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event is thrown will cause the process to terminate.

Have you tried to remove [STAThread] to see if the application exits correctly on exception? My guess would be some funky COM stuff, perhaps antivirus? Or something else installed on your computer but not your coworkers? ProcessMonitor might be useful for figuring out what is going on.

Are you handling more then the mentioned event here in the comments? Like the  Process or Thread Exit Events or whatever. Mentioning the UnhandledException in the comments makes me feel that there is still more in your app going on then you show as code.

@JonasH, I didn't try clearing [STAThread] because it's a WinForms project. I checked ProcessMonitor and it looks like the new process PID is not dying after running WerFault.exe. I'll check again for the exact cause.

@Ralf, This happened when I created a WinForms project and added only the throw to Program.cs, as shown in the example code. Although not shown in the example code, the same thing happened when I set the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event in Program.cs and tested it.
